# JSON Object Not Found

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON `ArrayList[222, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666, 777]`

I need to only store value `[333,444,555,666,777]` in my JSON ArrayList.

I already try the below code, but i failed to get JSON Object for value 444.
The error encountered are : `Exception: org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["4"] not found.`

```
//list to delete data
 int lengthJSONMerged = JSONmergedJSONDataLog.length();
int count= lengthJSONMerged - 5; //5 is the max number should be in the array

for(int u= count+1; u < lengthJSONMerged+1;u++) { 
            String str = Integer.toString(u);
            JSONArray arrSessionDouble=(JSONArray)JSONmergedJSONDataLog.get(str); 
}
```

The original data is below. I need to keep the latest 5 record.

```
 {"1":[{"sessionID":"222","loginTime":"2019-02-25 15:10:03"}],
 "2":[{"sessionID":"222","loginTime":"2019-02-25 15:10:05"}],
"3":[{"sessionID":"333","loginTime":"2019-02-25 15:10:11"}],
 "4":[{"sessionID":"444","loginTime":"2019-02-25 15:10:17"}],
 "5":[{"sessionID":"555","loginTime":"2019-02-25 15:10:26"}],
 "6":[{"sessionID":"666","loginTime":"2019-02-25 15:10:35"}],
 "7":[{"sessionID":"777","loginTime":"2019-02-25 17:09:30"}]}
```

Do you have any idea why I'm getting that error.
When i try to hard code and run my Java Program, i managed to get the value for attributes "4".

Code that i used to hard code and get the vakue for attributes 4.

```
JSONArray arrSessionDouble=(JSONArray)JSONmergedJSONDataLog.get("4");
```

Comment: how is count used in your function? why subtracting 5 and then adding 1 later?

Comment: 5 is the max number of record that I want to store in my JSONArray.

adding 1 is because current JSON Length is 7. For to ensure that all array is passing through the process, I add 1.

Comment: that's a strange way to define a loop. Even if it is not the problem (which I'm not sure about), you should change the way you iterate

Comment: where is using count,ut variable?u is initialised by ut, what's the value of ut?

Comment: `get` takes an int so why convert `u` to a String and why not use `getJSONArray` instead of type casting?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson The code's terminology is confusing, but the root item OP is parsing is an object (which keys are "1" to "8"), not an array.

Comment: @Aaron I was under the impression it was already parsed into a JSONArray but I could be wrong

Comment: yes, what Aaron said is correct. Key is from "1" to "8".  i managed to get value for "3" but when it comes to "4" it throw the json exception

Comment: @inayzi tell us what's the value of ut? problem will be solved

Comment: hi Dhanraj,I already corrected my code. but same error still occured

Comment: @inayzi Then I don't think the json data you posted in your question is what you have in `JSONmergedJSONDataLog` because with that data it makes no sense why getting "3" would work but not "4".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ArrayList[222, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666, 777]
```

So you want to store last 5 values so i assumes you took count variable as to get start of u variable.

```
int lengthJSONMerged = JSONmergedJSONDataLog.length();
int count= lengthJSONMerged - 5   // to get start of u

for(u=count;u<lengthJSONMerged;u++)    //lengthJSONMerged to loop upto 7 as arrayindex would be 6
{
  String str = Integer.toString(u);
  JSONArray arrSessionDouble=(JSONArray)JSONmergedJSONDataLog.get(str); //Here loop will run for u=2,3,4,5,6
}
```

So using above code your last 5 elements of array will get stored.
You might got mess up with using array index .
Don't forget array starts with index 0.
and your jason having numbering starting from 1.

**Where you went wrong in your code** :

```
for(u=count+1;u<lengthJSONMerged+1;u++)
```

So here your are starting loop from 3(count+1) and ending on 8(length i.e 7 + 1)
our array elements are

```
ArrayList[0]:- 222
ArrayList[1]:- 222
ArrayList[2]:- 333
ArrayList[3]:- 444 //your loops starts here
ArrayList[4]:- 555
ArrayList[5]:- 666
ArrayList[6]:- 777
ArrayList[7]:- null //here you are getting exception as you are pointing to node
ArrayList[8]:- null //Ends here
```

Answer (score 0):

When you get at the first iteration, the `lengthJSONMerged` value is 2:

```
int lengthJSONMerged = JSONmergedJSONDataLog.length(); // length of array is 7
int count= lengthJSONMerged - 5; // 7 - 5 = 2
```

What is exactly `uT` here?

```
for(int u= uT; u < lengthJSONMerged+1;u++)
```

if it's just an initialization and the `uT` variable is set at 1 (the value for the first JSON object in the array), then your for loop will be looking like this one:

```
for(int u = 1; u < 3; u++)
{ ... }
```

then it's pretty clear why you're not getting the fourth item.

Comment: OP's got an error for the fourth item though, it's not just lacking from his result : `Exception: org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["4"] not found.` You've underlined well what makes OP's code a bad MCVE though.

Comment: But `lengthJSONMerged` is seven, how did that turn into 3?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson because he subtract 5 earlier and the adds +1 in the check end condition

Comment: No, that was the `count` variable.